# getting public key format in javascript

Tags: javascript, public-key-encryption, public-key

I want to detect and validate (the format) of public keys, using javascript
are thy any libraries out there that can help me?
Basically I want a user to paste his key into a textarea and then I want to parse it to validate that this is in fact a rsa\ssh\etc. key, get the key name (description), bit size and any other relevant info.
Thank you.

Comment: no one has an has ever dealt with this? am I the first?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it with a regular expression.
This one matches the format that openssl outputs in.

```
var re = new RegExp("^-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{64}\r?\n[A-Za-z0-9+\/=]{38}==\r?\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r?\n?$");

re.test("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"+
"MIICWDCCAcGgAwIBAgIJAPoiU8TwxKfZMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEUxCzAJBgNV\n"+
"BAYTAkFVMRMwEQYDVQQIDApTb21lLVN0YXRlMSEwHwYDVQQKDBhJbnRlcm5ldCBX\n"+
"aWRnaXRzIFB0eSBMdGQwHhcNMTYwOTIxMjI1NzAzWhcNMjEwOTIwMjI1NzAzWjBF\n"+
"MQswCQYDVQQGEwJBVTETMBEGA1UECAwKU29tZS1TdGF0ZTEhMB8GA1UECgwYSW50\n"+
"ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0cyBQdHkgTHRkMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKB\n"+
"gQDKylIukm5ZNIFsFxqMNlqazn+bWlzSXnATvyu783KMTXGRMbKb8C+SVra3gofs\n"+
"0D7cgPPECMINFP0PEGBvN6iQXaJOL4YQUbl2FQOQEi6xOATytaWqaHy9DiZ8zeRs\n"+
"WhT/m+6fjefZD1FhBaIAPi2dy/TKSBo61SU9f2O0NyyIiQIDAQABo1AwTjAdBgNV\n"+
"HQ4EFgQUpyK5bWplT+owyTHUUD5FG5frc80wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUpyK5bWplT+ow\n"+
"yTHUUD5FG5frc80wDAYDVR0TBAUwAwEB/zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOBgQAupycX\n"+
"kF3RhL0bUmxbh1nZaZ0ZAuWh4A1pc5XjwSGYLhWMHpNmrIvGnlUuyQlyE6L45DR2\n"+
"JekCMC0TBK8mv2BpaUCcPA844LSix1lSoNvuGQ7GRuLvPDDY/v8I28mRLsLmqxg2\n"+
"uz3VNtJwu/igOCf4mDI9ZoQWPBRb+pqXJ42V8Q==\n"+
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n");

// outputs 'true'
```